# Merge using python error

Tags: python, python-2.7, merge

I am new to python. I was trying merge in Python but I am getting Error list assignment index out of range. Can anyone help me.

```
A = [4,5,7,9,0,1,2,3]

def merge(A,p,q,r):
    i = p
    j = q+1
    k = 0
    C = []
    while i<=q and j<=r:
        if A[i]<A[j]:
            C[k] = A[i]
            i = i + 1
        else:
            C[k] = A[j]
            j = j + 1
        k = k + 1
    if i!=q:
        for z in range(i,q+1):
            C[k] = A[z]
            k = k + 1

    if j!=r:
        for z in range(j,r+1):
            C[k] = A[z]
            k = k + 1

merge(A,0,3,7)
```

Comment: You've defined `C` as a zero-length array, so any access to it will be out of range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @chisaycock says, the problem is C has not the index k, so before to check that you must validate the lenct of C is same or greater than k

```
if len(C) > k:
... C[k]...
```